# How to convert Instant time to String?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to parse a `std::time::Instant` into a `String`, but I don't know how to do it properly.

```rust
use std::{time::Instant};

// let my_str: String = Instant::now();
```

The `Instant` struct doesn't seem to have a `parse` or `to_string` method.

I want to get the current timestamp, could be in any format, and store it in a struct/database as a String.

Comment: Note that instant does not contain a time, you can only measure the relative time passed between instants. Do you maybe want SystemTime instead?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I just want to get the current time, could be in any format, and store it in the database

Comment: look into `chrono` crate. if you get stuck i can add a code sample.

Comment: @boran chrono was merged into std::time, was it not?

Comment: @DownloadPizza i have no idea. maybe not released yet? There are not any major changes in the docs https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/index.html

Comment: @boran I may have misremebered, chrono is not discontinued at least so its not a bad call

Comment: If you want to store it in a database, you probably want to use a specific type like [`Timestamp`](https://docs.rs/postgres/latest/postgres/types/enum.Timestamp.html) for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [the documentation of `std::time::Instant` mentions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Instant.html):

> Instants are opaque types that can only be compared to one another.

For a more complete time library, which supports time zones and printing, use `chrono`, [whose documentation has a whole section about formatting time](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/#formatting-and-parsing).

If you want to store the time in a database, then you are most likely interested in the `to_rfc3339` method which serializes time as per ISO 8601/RFC3339:

```
use chrono::Utc;

fn main() {
    let time = Utc::now();

    println!("{}", time.to_rfc3339());
}
```

prints `2022-02-26T16:17:33.088851150+00:00`.